# Meromorphic extension example

Tags: complex-analysis

Meromorphic was defined as follows:

Let $M \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a region. $f$ is meromorphic on M if any $a\in M$ is a removable or pole singularity of $f$. This is to say that there are no essential singularities.

From there, the following was given:

Let $S \subseteq M$ be the discrete set of poles of $f$. Then $f$ has a unique holomorphic extension $g$ that is holomorphic on $M - S$ and if we are only concerned with partial functions on $M$ then $g$ is maximal.

My questions are the following:

What is a partial function? 
What would be an example of an $f$ and a $g$ in the situation provided above?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I guess you are just proving [Riemann theorem's on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem) ? (and you should think looking at another course, if the rest is as abstract as here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A "partial function" on $U$ is a function $f: V \to X$, where $X$ is any codomain and $V \subset U$. (In other words: it's only "partially defined" because in some places it doesn't make sense. A stock example: $f(x) = 1/x$ is a "partial function on the real line".)
2. Example: $f:  \mathbb C \to  \mathbb C^{*} : z \mapsto 1/z$, is meremorphic. $g: \mathbb C - \{0\} \to \mathbb C: z \mapsto 1/z$ is holomorphic on its domain, which is a subset of the domain of $f$. In this case, the domain $M$ is all of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: For 2: what does it mean for g to be an extension of then since the domain of g is a subset of the domain of f? It seems like the opposite of an extension in that sense unless my understanding of an extension is far too narrow.

Comment: I have no idea what that meant ... it certainly wasn't clear to me as I read it.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that I always thought that an extension function was one where the values are equal everywhere on a subset of the original domain but that the extension was defined in areas where the original function was not.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, too (and that's how it's *always* used in topology, where the "extension problem" is a classic). I figured that perhaps there was some description of $f$ or $M$ earlier that I wasn't seeing and that might make this clear...but it really just looks weird and/or badly written.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for your answer!